# How can cancellation laws be applied to deduce equality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $g,h, k$ belong to $G$.

Show that the following statement is true:

$$ghg=gkg \implies h=k$$

Show that the following statement is not necessarily true:

$$hgh=kgk \implies h=k$$

Comment: What have you tried? The first question should be relatively easy as ever member of the group has an inverse.

Comment: I tried left and right laws cancellation by adding putting  g^-1 to the left and right of both relation but I'm not sure if it's is right

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Comment: But what about the second relation I can't show h=k

Comment: You have to show that it is not necessarily true, for this you can give a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement follows by multiplying the equation by $g^{-1}$ from left and right.
The second statement has counterexamples. Take the group $S_n$ and let $h=g=id$ and $k=(12)$. Then we have $hgh=id=(12)(12)=kgk$, but $h\neq k$. So it also works with non-abelian groups.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the first: pre-multiply and post-multiply by $g^{-1}$

For the second part let $h=1,k=-1$ and pick $g$ arbitrary in $\mathbb Z^*$